# iTerm2 - how to run command in a pane code inside of a loop

Tags: python, iterm2, iterm

I'm trying to split panes in iTerm and run commands in each pane. If I run one command after another manually it's fine. However, when I run those same commands inside of a loop I have a problem. Can anyone help?

```
for repo in commands["run"]:
            split = await session.async_split_pane(vertical=True)
            await split.async_send_text(f'cd Projects/{repo}')
            if repo["yarn"] == True:
               # why does this not run? it doesn't "hit the return key"
               await split.async_send_text('yarn start')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! It's necessary to add a `\n` after each string sent to iTerm2